# relations on an attribute that can be null in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `Order` model like this :

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'order_id';
    protected $fillable = ['desc', 'date_at', 'status'];

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'creator', 'user_id');
    }

    public function validator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'validator', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

In the fields list there is a `validator` that can be set after creation of an instance of `Order` model Or not initialized at all.

Since **validatior** is nullable whenever I want to return an order I got an error like this :

```
Undefined property: Modules\\Order\\Entities\\Order::$validator
```

Comment: I think you can't define relationship that way. Try to append it as attribute. The attribute can be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is with the name of the validator function since I assume is a key word in Laravel, try changing the name of the function to something else. and do a `composer dump-autoload` just in case